# run node apache-exporter in same docker container as Apache

Tags: apache-http-server, docker, prometheus

I am running node `apache-exporter` (https://github.com/Lusitaniae/apache_exporter) in the same Docker container (build from httpd image) as Apache itself.
(So am able to distribute the service directly with the container by one Dockerfile and one docker-compose other like using two Dockerfiles and combine the 2 containers in one docker-compose file.)

The `apache-exporter` (and the Apache server) runs and I can see the `apache-up` data in Prometheus/Grafana.

I have inserted the `Location` block inside my `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
  ServerAlias www.XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
  <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    #Require local
    Require host example.com
    #Require ip YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY 
  </Location>
  Redirect permanent / https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
</VirtualHost>
```

`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` = external IP, `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY` = IP inside docker network and loaded the modules

```
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
```

But I got the error:

```
level=error msg="Error scraping apache: error scraping apache: Get \"https:///XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXserver-status/?auto\": dial tcp: lookup XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXserver-status on YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY: no such host" source="apache_exporter.go:571"
```

What is wrong? Is a `/` missing somewhere? Do I have to write the  `Location` block inside another `VirtualHost` block using another `ServerName`? Do I have to set `--scrape_uri`?
I guess it is just a stupid mistake by me because the `/` is missing between IP and `server-status`. I seems that the `Location` is not considered and thus the URL is processed by `Redirect permanent`. Using several `ProxyPass` inside a `VirtualHost` is possible when placing the `/` redirection last.

I want to restrict access to `server-status` to the Apache-container itself.

Comment: Simply removing `Redirect permanent` might help. That is, an automatic redirect to `server-status` may already be in place.

Comment: Thanks a lot - it works. I also needed a `Require all granted` inside the location block.

Comment: You're welcome. Good to know things got figured out. =)

Answer (score 1):

It works using this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
  ServerAlias www.XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
  <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Require all granted
    Require host example.com
  </Location>  
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).